# Creating WebStorm shortcut to navigate to another file basing on current file name

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm developing AngularJS app and I have file `one-two-three-directive.js` opened. I'd like to have/create a shortcut which will navigate to file `one_two_three.html` in the same project (dashes turn into underscores and there is no `directive` word).

Is there any way to achieve this (any existing plugin or other way will be appreciated).

Answer (score 0):

Not currently possible out of the box, related ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265643.
I'd suggest checking the [Angular Component Folding](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10090-angular-component-folding) - see if it works for you

Comment: Unfortunately, Angular Component Folding plugin "groups files which have same name and different extensions", but my files don't have same names.